# Clojure sequence with index for GridBagLayout

Tags: swing, clojure, gridbaglayout

I am writing code to fill a java.awt.GridBagLayout with "rows" of controls. For each row, I have a method call of the form

```
(.add panel CONTROL (fill-gbc 0 INDEX ...))
```

where CONTROL is the Swing control to place at this row (i.e.: `(JLabel. "Hello")`) and INDEX is the `gridy` for that control (`fill-gbc` fills a single, mutable, `GridBagContraints` object and returns it -- it accepts keyword optional parameters for `gridwidth`, `gridheight`, etc.)

I would like to create a vector of the row contents (the `(.add panel ...)` calls) and use `(map-indexed ...)` to fill in the INDEX value.

The only way that I can come up with do do this is to make each `(.add panel ...)` an anonymous function of one parameter (the index):

```
(dorun (map-indexed #(%2 %1)
                    [#(.add panel (.JLabel "Hello") (fill-gbc 0 %)) ...]))
```

Is there a better way to do this, perhaps with a macro (I'll need this pattern several times in my application for various dialog boxes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could abstract this away into a function, then you can use it wherever you need it.

```
(defn add-on-row [panel c]
  (dorun
   (map-indexed
    #(%2 %1)
    [#(.add panel c (fill-gbc 0 %)) ...])))
```

You'd just pass parameters for whatever information will ever vary.

Furthermore, I wrote a little macro for adding a bunch of things to a container.

```
(defmacro add [cmp & things]
  (cons
   'do
   (for [thing things]
     `(.add ~cmp ~@(if (vector? thing) thing [thing])))))
```

That let's you write stuff like this:

```
(add 
 panel 
 [(JLabel. "Hello") "more arguments"] 
 (JLabel "Hello!"))
```

Not sure if that's helpful for you in this situation, but it might be.